# Verify/checksum of MS-SQL backup doesn't work (as I expected)

Tags: sql-server

When doing MS-SQL backup of a database you can choose these two options in SSMS:

[image]

But if I afterward change a bit in the backup-file (.bak) and do a restore or `Verify Backup Media` the database is restored without any error/warning!
I did a checksum of the original and modified backup-file (.bak) and they sure are different.

Is this as expected?

I thought a checksum was added to the backup-file that would be checked when doing a restore, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Or at least the changes/corruption must be severe to trigger a restore error.

I also tried to make a backup using  SQLCMD and using the option "...WITH CHECKSUM"...same result.

Did the test on SQL Server 2017

I compress my backups which include a checksum, so I can rely on that, but scary you can't rely on the built-in checksum, at least not in the above scenario.

Comment: how do you "change a bit" in the backup-file?

Comment: With a binary editor, is this case the one included with Visual Studio
But as long as the checksum is different between the two files, then one can be sure the files are actually different, right.

Comment: ok, well mssql performes the checksum on page level not on file level. So you might just have caught some unimportant metadata or whatever. Have you performed a DBCC CHECKDB on this DB you have restored from your edited bak-file?

Comment: Nope....I haven't done any further checking, I have to look into `DBCC CHECKDB` what ever that that is.

Comment: But I wonder if `DBCC CHECKDB` will actually catch all bit-flips/corruptions?
My purpose was to quickly verify my backup files. And I assume you can only do `DBCC CHECKDB` after you actually restore the database. I think I just calculate a checksum and attach it to the backup file in the backup-script.

Comment: I don't know if it will catch it, but I guess if it won't, It wouldn't matter. I can also imagine that mssql is able to correct such small changes as you did for your test. Yes it is corret, the DB needs to be online for CHECKDB.
Sure is, that your test with a checksum of a file does not represent the checksum test of a mssql backup